Common ways to fault tolerantly prepare a stabilizer state
It is my impression that it is much easier to fault tolerantly prepare a stabilizer state than it is to prepare a magic state.
What are some common ways to fault tolerantly prepare a given stabilizer state, for example a cat state? Is there a canonical best choice or are different methods/ different circuits better for different purposes?

Unfortunately, the vast majority of logical operations are pretty encoding-specific.
If you already can already do the full Clifford group fault-tolerantly then you can use things like the techniques in Gottesman's thesis. You may have to distill resource states to do some gates (e.g. S or H). You may also get lucky and have a ZX duality which gives part of the Clifford group. In surface codes, lattice surgery will allow you to do the full Clifford group.
The most generic approach is to run the encoding circuit of your code protected by a concatenated code.** This is the approach taken for fault-tolerance proofs using quantum low-density parity check (LDPC) codes.
You could also take a code-switching approach (e.g. 3D color codes), but to my knowledge this hasn't been used in any fault-tolerance proofs.
** as an afterthought, you could just as well use any other code family for which you know how to perform Clifford gates (e.g. surface codes)

What if I am just trying to prepare $ n $ ancilla qubits in the $ n $ qubit cat state, is there a best way to do that? In other words I'm not trying to initialize my circuit to a cat state but just to use some ancilla qubits in that particular stabilizer state, does that provide any more useful context?

An n qubit (unencoded) cat state such as what you would do in Shor-style syndrome extraction? Are you interested in an adversarial or stochastic setting? Preparing an unencoded n-qubit cat state (with n large) subject to stochastic errors is quite difficult, but the equivalent task subject to adversarial noise is done frequently in code concatenation.
